# Customize checkbox styles with ivh-treeview

Tags: javascript, html, css, treeview

I am using [angular-ivh-treeview](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview) to render a hierarchical checkbox list. It is working fine however I have trouble styling the checkboxes. If I am correct I have to use a custom template and then apply some ::before/::after styles to the label?

What I got so far is [here](http://jsbin.com/yizonuxano/edit?html,css,js,output), is this the right way to approach it? I am not sure how to set the id dynamically in the custom template so at the moment all nodes have the same id which only change the color of the first node.

Template:

```
template: [
      '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox-primaryblue">',
      '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="12">',
      '<label  class="custom-control-label" for="12">',
      '{{::trvw.label(node)}}',
      '</label>',
      '</div>',
    ]
```

CSS

```
.custom-control {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;

}

.custom-control-input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;

}

.custom-control-label::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: .25rem;
    left: -1.5rem;
    display: block;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    content: "";
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;   
    background-color: yellow;
}

.custom-control-label::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: .25rem;
    left: -1.5rem;
    display: block;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    content: "";
}

.custom-checkbox-primaryblue .custom-control-label {
    outline: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}


.custom-control-input:checked + .custom-control-label::before {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: I guess I wonder how to set the id and for dynamically in the template instead of giving all checkboxes the same id.